# I ran into a problem in figma, the whole project disappeared because of union

Tags: figma

I was working in figma[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKWDl.jpg), and accidentally touched an extra button, now I don't know how to remove it and return to the project. how do I remove this?

I tried to return everything using combination ctrl+z, it didn't help :(